# Make GWT window's title editable

Tags: window, smartgwt

I need the title of smartGWT Windows to be editable. And I have to do it dynamically because the numbers of windows are variable.

I proceeded as follow:

1) I create a list of random IDs for the windows, when they are loaded

```
private String randomId = "title" + Random.nextInt();
```

2) I implemented a method to create the window and set its title

```
@Override
public final Canvas getCanvas() {
    if (window == null) {
        window = new Window();
        window.setTitle(getTitle(model));
```

3)

```
private String getTitle(E model) {
        return "<span contenteditable=\"true\" style=\"cursor: text\" id=\"" + randomId + "\">" + model.getName() + "</span>";
}
```

3) I call a method to edit the window in case it is clicked

```
window.addDrawHandler(event -> setupTitleEditing(randomId));
```

4) I implemented the method as follows:

```
private native void setupTitleEditing(String name)/*-{
    document.getElementById(name).bind('click', function() {
        $(this).attr('contentEditable', true);
        }).blur(function() {
        $(this).attr('contentEditable', false);
        });
}-*/;
```

The element span is consider to be null in step 4) even it exist with the correct ID (browser inspector).

My question is: Is there a direct method to do that in java using GWT methods? If not, what did I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My proposed solution is still with some problem but I can show you what you did wrong and then you may find the complete solution.

Within the JSNI method `setupTitleEditing(String name)`, you should use `$doc` instead `document`. The reason is that (quote from Chapter 11, GWT In Action, 2nd Edition)

> a GWT application could be (and usually is) loaded into a frame within
>   the browser. This means that the visibility of the `document` variable
>   is guaranteed. GWT provides the `$doc` JavaScript variable instead, which it guarantees to link to the standard `document` variable regardless of how the application is loaded into the browser.

Note the object returned by `$doc.getElementById(name)` DOES NOT have the method 'bind' or 'blur'. You'll have to do this assignment

```
$doc.getElementById(name).onclick = function(){
   $(this).attr('contentEditable', true);
};
```

I implemented this solution and I ran it. I was able to edit the title, but not without a hassle. The cursor of the `<span>` element doesn't show up willingly. It always took me to do a sequence of clicks here and there to finally bring up the cursor and only after that I can edit the title. I don't know why, but it looks like right clicking on the title to get the context menu and then clicking on `inspect element` could always make the cursor show up.

P.S. You tagged your post with `'smartgwt'` instead of `'gwt'` because the widget classes `Canvas` and `Window` mentioned in your question belong to `SmartGWT` instead of vanilla `GWT`. Am I right? Someone edited your tags and replaced `'smartgwt'` with `'gwt'`. I didn't realized that until I went through the GWT's javadoc and found that its `Window` class doesn't have a method with the name `addDrawHandler` and the `Window` class is also not a subclass of `Canvas`.

Although the solution might not be specific to SmartGWT, I suggest you 1) add the tag back so that someone familiar with SmartGWT framework might come up and help, and 2) add links to the classes when you mention them like this [Canvas](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html) and [Window](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Window.html).

Comment: Yes it is very annoying that I have to click everywhere before the content becomes editable. Anyone has an idea about how to proceed to remove this bug?